# Turn Array of Selenium Webdriver Elements into their values?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to scrape this website, which has a table. One of the rows contained the info i needed (Let's just say each cell looked like one of these entries: [12%, 34%, 27%, 38%])

I selected all of these percentages by using this line:

```
notes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'%')]").text
```

*There was no better was to do this; there were no class names or id names for me to select*

After I printed this array, it gave me this input:
[image: Element Array Input]

I'm assuming these are the elements of the percentages, but how do I convert this array to print out the array with the actual percentages (ex. [12%, 34%, 27%, 38%])?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` (all selenium *find_elements...* methods return a list) returns a Python `list`, you have to call `.text` on list items, not the list itself.

```
notes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'%')]")
notes = [note.text for note in notes]
```